# How do I apply Tfidf_vectorizer to the whole pandas column?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, nlp, tf-idf

First of all I'm kinda new to NLP, so I might have understood a concept in a wrong way or something

I am trying to find a way to vectorize the whole column as 1 text, and then after getting the results, I would like to fit the model I'm using to my target set.

I am currently using a pipeline to vectorize my dataframe columns, but I believe that they are being vectorized 1 by 1, instead of joining all the columns together and then doing it.

Here's an exaggerated example of my dataset:

```
   data                                                 target
1 "conventional normal breast cancer test"              breast cancer test
2 "regular and conventional normal lung cancer test"    lung cancer test
```

Basically, I would like to give the terms "breast" and "lung" a high tfidf score because it is unique, and I don't want my model to mistake these 2 types of data because they seem similar

My Current Code:

```
vectorizer = feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 3),
                         analyzer='word',)

pipe = pipeline.Pipeline([
('vectorizer', vectorizer),
('clf', linear_model.LogisticRegression())])

pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_predicted = pipe.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: Your example is working on my computer. The weights are computed accurately as far as I can see. To be sure, you can access the IDF matrix by running ```pipe.steps[0][1].transform(X_train).todense()```

Comment: @Lawis thanks a lot!
 I will try it now

Comment: Okay, I tried it on my full dataset, but it gave a MemoryError, I guess 8GB of RAM are not enough to apply the todense() method on 400K records

Comment: Yes, sklearn use sparse matrix objects as there are many "0" in IDF matrix and thus they use an efficient way to store in memory this matrix without raising OOM errors. But with only a few examples to test it should work and you should see that rare ngrams will have higher score.